# searching for character with lowercase and uppercase

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON data

```
[
{"lastName":"Noyce","gender":"Male","patientID":19389,"firstName":"Scott","age":"53Y,"}, 
{"lastName":"noyce724","gender":"Male","patientID":24607,"firstName":"rita","age":"0Y,"}
]

var searchBarInput = TextInput.value;
var results = []; // initialize array of results
for (var i = 0; i < recentPatientsList.length; ++i) {
  if (recentPatientsList[i].lastName.indexOf(searchBarInput) == 0) {
    results.push(recentPatientsList[i].lastName);
  }
}
alert('Results: ' + results.toString());
```

I get the result, but i want it for both matching uppercase and lowercase when i search for a character which starts in the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toUpperCase` on both of the strings

```
if (recentPatientsList[i].lastName.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchBarInput.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(recentPatientsList[i].lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBarInput.toLowerCase()) == 0)
```

Comment: aaaah the alternative to `toUpperCase`   =P